# Why am I not getting the complete URL parameters using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am using the following cut/paste function to get the URL parameters.

```
function getUrlVars() 
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    var i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    
    return vars;
}
```

It works perfectly fine but when I get a URL like:

```
http://example.com/login.html?redirecturl=http://example.com/game_detail.html?id=3&reminderid=5
```

and I do something like:

```
loginVars = getUrlVars();
alert("redirecting to: "+loginVars['redirecturl']);
```

I get only:

```
redirecting to: http://example.com/game_detail.html?id
```

but what I want is the whole: `http://example.com/game_detail.html?id=3&reminderid=5`

Comment: 1) How is it related to jQuery? 2) `but what I want is the whole` you will never 'guess' automatically whether all arguments are the part of the `redirecturl` or the part of the `login.html?` query. Normally they should be URL encoded to be the part of `redirecturl=` parameter. `login.html` does not operate with separate parameters, but rather with query_string.. How should your script know about it?

Comment: I would use location.search and test if I had another url in there.

Comment: is it working for you ??? i hope you got my point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said, in general you can not 'guess', especially when parameters (by RFC) belong to the original URL, not to the URL inside of one of those parameters, but in application to your example you can use

```
var str = 'http://someurl.com/login.html?redirecturl='+                 
          'http://someurl.com/game_detail.html?id=3&reminderid=5', 
    separator = 'redirecturl=';

alert(str.substring(str.indexOf(separator)+separator.length));​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```